# QPython on Nexus 9: PIE error

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, qpython

I am getting the following "error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported." when trying to run scripts.

Does QPython run on Android 5.0? Is it an issue with the 64bit version of Lollipop?

Answer (score 0):

I think QPython doesn't support  PIE yet.